# Ghostscript Printing PDF dPDFFitPage Incorrect Sizes

Tags: printing, ghostscript

Am having issues with printing different sized PDF's using GhostScript (V9.05).

The PDF in question is A3 landscape however when printing using ghost script using the following command line arguments the result is printed in A4 portrait and cuts off half of the content.

Commad line arguments:

"-sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dPDFFitPage -dPrinted=false -dNoCancel -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="\spool\HP LaserJet P2050 Series PCL6 (A4)" "C:\Users\dmeggs\AppData\Local\Temp\iPlan_Printing_k4gjaoip.pdf""

I've tried many combinations of parameters, most seem to have no effect.  Ideally I want the printer to print the PDF based on the PDF properties as this will be used to print A4, A3, portrait and landscape documents.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as a new answer as its too big for a comment.

If the output from pswrite and epswrite work then the printer is a PostScript printer.

Pdfwrite produces PDF files, so presumably you don't want to do that, given the input is a PDF file :-) Some PostScript printers can in fact print PDF files too, but this is comparatively unusual.

Rather than use psweite (or epswrite) I would suggest that you use ps2write (which will produce PostScript language level 2 as output) and send the resulting file to the printer.

In an ideal world your printer would then do media selection based on the media request in the PostScript program), but not all printers manage this. In part because printers don't always know which media is in which tray, if multiple media are available.

However, you can then write reasonably simple PostScript code which you can prepend to the file which will allow you to determine the requested page size. Assuming you know how to control tray/media selection in your printer you can have the PostScritp program do that for you.

Unfortunately I can't give you much detail on how to do this, as it depends a great deal on the specific printer.

Comment: Thanks Ken, In the end I have opted for -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -dPrinted=false -dNoCancel -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile= This appears to be working on an A4 only printer for both A4 and A3 sized PDF's which is OK for now.  I'm sure at some point they will require it to be able to print out on both A4 and A3 size at which point I will have to look up apending a postscript code file and selecting the correct printer tray.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I presume the printer is an A4 printer ? In order for GS to scale the page correctly you need to tell it what the page size is. It can't tell from the printer name. Try setting -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA

That sets the media to A4, and tells GS it can't be altered, the -dPDFFITPAGE switch will then fit the PDF media request to the declared media, by scaling.

If that doesn't work, then I'll need to see your PDF file.

Comment: Thanks Ken that worked a treat.  And yes the test printer was A4.  However in the live environment they are using a printer which does both A4 and A3 printing.  I need to be able to handle both cases, but I wont know up front if the PDF has A4 content or A3 content.  Is it possible to allow the printer to decide?

Comment: I'm afraid not, no. Ghostscript needs to know before it creates the bitmap. The way the mswinpr2 device works is to create a printer device context, render the bitmap to the context and then tell it to print itself. Does the printer you are printing to not accept any of PCL, PDF, PostScript or XPS as input ? NB it does not matter what size the media in the PDF is, only the printer media. Unless you tell it otherwise GS will create a bitmap big enough for the declared media in the PDF file, but I have no idea how you would select the correct media on the printer.

Comment: I've tried changing the -sDEVICE parameter and it appears to be able to print to the same printer.  I have tried -sDEVICE=pswrite, sDEVICE=epswrite which worked (it printed), -sDEVICE=pdfwrite didn't send anything to the printer.  Are you saying that if I could use a different device driver then I could achieve this?